# How do you bind to a property in a xaml code-behind if the usercontrol's datacontext is a view-model?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I have a UserControl who's DataContext is being set to an instance of a ViewModel (using MVVM). But, I have controls within the UserControl which need to be bound to properties that only pertain to the view (which is why I placed them in code behind). I'm not sure how to bind this in xaml appropriately:

Note: `SelectedOrderType` is a property on the View-Model, and `OrderTypes` is a property on the UserControl itself.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.OrderControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Name="OrderUserControl">
  <Grid>
    ...
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OrderTypes, ElementName=OrderUserControl}"
              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedOrderType}"
              SelectedValuePath="OrderTypeCode"
              DisplayMemberPath="OrderTypeName" />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>


public partial class OrderControl : UserControl
{
    public OrderControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        OrderTypes = ...;
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<OrderTypeInfo> OrderTypes { get; private set; }
}
```

---

Also, I know I can simply create a property on the View-Model, and I get that some people would suggest that that would be the correct place to put it... but I really would like to know how I could do what I'm attempting to do if not for this scenario, maybe for other scenarios in the future?

Comment: I think what you wrote is actually okay, so this is the way to do that. This doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but would you not need to make a dependency property on your user control for "SelectedOrderType" and bind the the View Model to that property not bind directly to the view model from the user control.

That way your UserControl is not dependent on the view model?

Edit:

I think you could set it up the way you have it, but the binding for SelectedOrderType would need to be something like {Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedOrderType, ElementName=OrderUserControl}